# InfluxDB Query for Tag Values With a Specific Additional Tag

Tags: influxdb

If I have some influx data like:

```
testMes,feed=test,sourcetype=type1 records=5
testMes,feed=test2,sourcetype=type2 records=10
testMes,feed=test3 records=15
```

I'm trying to get a list of tag values with key "feed" where the sourcetype tag equals a value "type1".  So in the case above I would get just the tag "test".  I have tried a query but I know I am way off and after reading the syntax documentation I'm not making progress.  Any help on the correct syntax would be appreciated. I have tried:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "testMes" WITH KEY="feed" WHERE sourcetype="type1"
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? My guess is that you get empty resultset. Try to use single quotes in WHERE part:  `sourcetype='type1'`.

Comment: It is just an empty result set like you guessed even with single quotes.  I believe I have a working solution by doing the following: SELECT feed, records FROM "testMes" WHERE "sourcetype"='type1' GROUP BY feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were very close :-) 
the correct syntax is ..

show tag values from "testMes" with key = "feed"  where sourcetype = 'type1'

Comment: was it really just the single quotes at the end?  I was sure I tried that but I guess not.  Thanks!